# Android - How to generate lines between linearlayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to use XML to generate a UI that looks like this.

The blue tick button and the TextView is aligned with a LinearLayout placed vertically, so there is a total of 3 LinearLayouts in a Relative Layout. 
And now I need to add a line that sits between each tick button, with the alignment that looks like that.

Image looks like that :

[Image UI](http://cl.ly/image/3Y1P0t0N2G2E)

What layout do I go about using to achieve this?

This is my current code : (SOLUTION)

I have modified my solution based on @Piyush Gupta's provided solution! Thanks for the help everyone!

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000"
                android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000"
                android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearlayout1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#F14E23"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#000"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#000"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your xml with following code. you can adjust weight as per your requirements.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This actually also works, but there is a gap between the lines and the buttons. But for another implementation that requires this implementation can also be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view to show this kind of line. show view between linear layouts and use `android:layout_toRightOf=""` attribute to keep the layout organized.

```
  <View  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:background="@color/black"
         android:layout_height="1dip" />
```

Comment: Yes I can generate the line I just dont know how to fit it between the buttons and center it vertically. The lines also need to have dynamic width as it should also scale to fit on a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/button" />

            <View  android:layout_width="60dp"
             android:background="@color/black"
             android:layout_height="1dip"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
             />

         </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <View  android:layout_width="60dp"
         android:background="@color/black"
         android:layout_height="1dip"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
         />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/button" />

            <View  android:layout_width="60dp"
             android:background="@color/black"
             android:layout_height="1dip"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
             />

         </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <View  android:layout_width="60dp"
             android:background="@color/black"
             android:layout_height="1dip"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
             />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/button" />

            </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample! However it looks like that now... http://cl.ly/image/0K0U1p0z3o0a Still not what I hope to achieve, I wish for the line to be touching the buttons, and for the line to be centered vertically within the button layer and not also the TextView included.

Comment: Hi Hari, I tried but it still looks weird as the line sticks to button's left hand side and is detached from button on the right...

Comment: @cokeby can you show a screen shot?
because I tried in my computer and it looks to be working normal

Comment: Hari, my mistake, I tried again a second time and it looks like this now : http://cl.ly/image/2v3A2A410K2r
However, its not dynamic for all screen sizes as the pixel width for the line is fixed.

Comment: @cokeby yes I know, I just gave an example of how you can achieve that

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement try undermentioned code in xml file where ever you require. This will create line for you.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@color/black" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hoping that U can manage Linear Layout "weight" option.